# I get the message "No module named django" even though it is installed and is in the system path

Tags: python, django

I am setting up django on my system using this tutorial, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/development_environment. I did everything exactly as it told me to, but when I run the command "py -3 -m django --version", I get the message : "C:\Users\Vivek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe: No module named django". I checked and the django installation is in the system path, and I can import django in python. 
What can I do to fix this error?

Comment: To you maybe have a 64 bit version and a 32 bit version installed?

Comment: do you have any other python version installed on your computer?
also see if you have django in pip installed list
you can see all of them by typing `pip freeze`
alternatively try to install django inside a virtualenv with `virtualenv env` and `env\Scripts\activate` and then `pip install django` - it'll only install it for that local env

Comment: @Megalng , My python version is 32 bit.

Comment: @OlafGórski , I did install django inside a virtual environment. Django is in the pip installed list.

Comment: okay, what does the `pip freeze` command return to you?

Comment: @OlafGórski ,  it returns "Django==2.0.3
pytz==2018.3"

Comment: Have you activated your virtual environment?

Comment: @PatJones , yes the environment is activated, and the name of the environment is displayed inside brackets.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that "py -3 -m django --version" was not the correct command for my version of python (3.6.4 32 bit); I replaced it with "python -3 -m django --version" and it worked.